# Checking if another computer is turned on or off

Tags: c#, ping

Is there anyway to check if a computer is turned on / off using C#?

I have tried using this.

```
private static bool IsMachineUp(string hostName)
    {
        bool retVal = false;
        try
        {
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();
            PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
            // Use the default Ttl value which is 128,
            // but change the fragmentation behavior.
            options.DontFragment = true;
            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted.
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            int timeout = 120;

            PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(hostName, timeout, buffer, options);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                retVal = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retVal = false;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

But the problem is it always returns true when finding an ip of internal network and always returns false when finding by external network.

Is there any other way?? Just to determine whether a pc is turned on or off.

Or if external network is not available then is there a way to find if the ip of external network is actually used by a computer?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you need the ```data```, but have you checked whether you can ping the computer in the external network with CMD > ping?

Comment: There is no reliable way to tell if a computer outside a network you control is off over the internet. The best you can tell is if something responds or not. But there may be multiple devices mapped to one IP so you can't distinguish between them, and any query could be dropped or filtered for any of a number of reasons, resulting in false negatives.

Comment: It's as user1937198 said. We are not control system engineers to be hooking monitors and actuators into the physical power supplies or other parts of machines.